# how to fetch the input parameters and the return parameter passed to a python function using java

Tags: java, python, reflection

I have written a Python script which takes input parameters. Now I need to fetch the input parameters to a variable. How can this be achieved as we use reflection in Java?

```
class Song(object):

        def __init__(self, lyrics):
            self.lyrics = lyrics

        def sing_me_a_song(self):
            for line in self.lyrics:
                print line

happy_bday = Song(["Happy birthday to you",
                   "I don't want to get sued",
                   "So I'll stop right there"])

bulls_on_parade = Song(["They rally around tha family",
                        "With pockets full of shells"])

happy_bday.sing_me_a_song()

bulls_on_parade.sing_me_a_song()
```

Comment: Do you mean input parameters from command line? or some other program that imports your script?

Comment: What is your problem exactly? The source code you posted works, you can add new songs by `Song(...)`

Comment: i need to write a new script which has to fetch the method arguments (input parameters)present  in the script.In java we use reflection but i dont know how w e can do it in python